# Replace Missing Values with Most Frequent number under Condition

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, missing-data, mode

I'm trying to replace missing values of column "Age" but under condition of other columns on this data [Titanic - Machine Learning from Disaster](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)

```
df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]
```

I tried to do that using **SimpleImputer**:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
Imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')

Imputer.fit_transform( pd.DataFrame(df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]) )
```

but it doesn't work and tried to save values to the column:

```
df.loc[(df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]), 'Age'] = Imputer.fit_transform( pd.DataFrame(df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]) )
```

but doesn't work also.

I tried to do it manually using **fillna()**

```
df.loc[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1), 'Age'].fillna(int(df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)].mode()), inplace=True)
```

I tried to use indexes to access rows and update their values:

```
mod = int(df.Age[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)].mode())
indices = df.loc[(df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Sex == 0) & (df.Pclass == 1), 'Age'].isnull().index
df.loc[ind, 'Age'] = mod
df[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].isnull().sum()
```

it worked and the output was: 0, but when I'm trying to apply it in for loop it gives me an error

```
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,4):    
        indices = df.loc[(df.Sex == i) & (df.Pclass == j), 'Age'].isnull().index
        mod = int(df.Age[(df['Sex'] == i) & (df['Pclass'] == j)].mode())
        df.loc[ind, 'Age'] = mod
```

I want to know what is the wrong of first 2 ways an why the 3rd doesn't work in loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works well but I don't know why above don't work!

```
Imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(1,4):
        ls = np.array(df.Age[((df.Sex==i) & (df.Pclass==j))]).reshape(-1,1)
        df.Age[((df.Sex==i) & (df.Pclass==j))] = Imputer.fit_transform(ls)[:,0]
df.Age.isnull().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method pad. It takes the most recent value. Afterward, you can drop certain values based on conditions from other columns.

```
df.fillna(method='pad')
```

Comment: ```for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,4):    
        df.Age[(df.Sex == i) & (df.Pclass == j)].fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
        
df[(df['Sex'] == 0) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].isnull().sum()```
The missing values still exist